# How to avoid messed up values due to the this context in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a variable declared in a module and changed the value in one function and then tried to access it in another function and it gave a different value. here is a simplified version of the code:

```
module test{
export class tester{
    boo: boolean = false;
    function1(){
        this.boo = true;
     }
     function2(){ 
         console.log(this.boo);
     }
}
}
```

then it is called from the window object

```
window.onload = function () {
    var x = new test.tester();
    x.function1();
    x.function2();
}
```

I keep ending up with false as the value for the boolean even though it is set to true in a previous function in the module. I assume the context for the this is being changed and causes an issue?

I tend to fix these issues by using a global variable so that the this context would not affect it but I think there should be a better solution than making any variable global when the this context is changed and it causes an error. I would like some advice on how to avoid this in the future as well in similar situations as well.

EDIT: changed variable name as Steve Fenton suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your example is that you create a local variable with the same name as your module. In your line `var test = new test.tester();` the variable test on the right-hand side of the expression will not be your module, but the local `var test` you just declared on the left-hand side.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var testInstance = new test.tester();
    testInstance.function1();
    testInstance.function2();
}
```

This would even be the case if you tried to use `test` within the same function before your `var test` as variables are hoisted (any variables declared inside a function are treated as if they are declared right at the top of the function).

Comment: Oh thats interesting, it was a mistake I made while writing the example. thanks for this answer as i didnt know about that.